# View a data frame with many columns

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a data set with 85 columns. I cannot view the later columns with the `View()` function.

Is there a command to view all columns in the data frame?

Comment: are you working with RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to scroll to the right in the window opened by `View()`. In RStudio, there is an option above the column names to scroll to the right or to the left; columns 1-50 are displayed by default.

Furthermore, you might use the following functions to take a look at your data:

```
names(data)
str(data)
View(data[, 51:100])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("data_viewer_max_columns", 1000L)
```

will change the number of columns visble and make this change permanent.